# Why doesn't Azure Pipelines pick up commit on GitHub?

Tags: azure, build, azure-pipelines

We use Azure Pipelines for our CI/CD processes since a few weeks. The CI pipeline gets code from GitHub, builds, tests and creates a deploy package.

From the beginning I am quite certain that every commit got detected as intended, but recently that is not the case. Manual triggers and scheduled triggers work, but continuous integration does not.

What could be the causes for this?

In the pipeline, we checked the box for "continuous integration", and we use the recommended GitHup App to provide authorization. This is verified to work, we can see the authorized GitHub repos in the pipelines settings.

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No, it’s just that it doesn’t trigger. Is there a place to look for errors?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out below workarounds? how did it go?

Comment: I think it has to do with authorization; we set up the Azure "app" in GitHub, and used that to access the code, but when I switched to a "system user" it started to work. Somewhere I read that the Azure app only works for one pipeline, and maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the github branch you committed to is included in the **Branch filters**. If it is not included. Click Add to add the branch.

[image]

Check if there is skip CI command(eg.`[skip ci]`) in commit message. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits) for more information.

If CI trigger is not working even all the settings are correct. You can try below workarounds:

1,Disable the CI trigger, save, then re-enable it and save it again.

2,Clone your build definition. See below screenshot

[image]

3, Create a new build pipeline with the same trigger and settings.

If all above arenot working. You can go to [this site](https://status.dev.azure.com/) to see if there is a server outage of azure devops.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up changing how we connect from Azure Pipelines to GitHub. The recommended way is to install the Azure App in GitHub and connect using that in Pipelines. My experience is that it worked at first, but stopped working. I read somewhere that only the first connection works with webhooks, so maybe we tried it somewhere else or something that broke it. I ended up using a GitHub servic account to pull and listen for webhooks, and that works just as expected.

Comment: Could you please explain the workaround in a bit more detail? It might help others experiencing similar issues.

Comment: @Jaywalker I created a normal user account in GitHub and use it as a "service" account. When we set up the Azure Pipeline, I use that account and password like a normal account. It's the part with the Azure App in GitHub that didn't work for us.